# Image enlarge on click and need scroll

Tags: jquery, plugins

I am looking for a JQuery plugin that has the feature to enlarge a image on clicking it and i need a scroll bar in the enlarged image. The scroll can be of any type. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Fancybox may help you. http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples What's the scrollbar for? Like, scrolling the image if it's larger than the screen? That's not a very responsive approach :)

Comment: Yea i know. But that's the requirement. Check the below link. They want something like that. http://www.myntra.com/tshirts/kook-n-keech-marvel/kook-n-keech-marvel-men-black--blue-printed-t-shirt/407056/buy?src=search&uq=&q=shopping-offer16&p=4

Comment: I need something like this - http://www.myntra.com/tshirts/kook-n-keech-marvel/kook-n-keech-marvel-men-black--blue-printed-t-shirt/407056/buy?src=search&uq=&q=shopping-offer16&p=4

Comment: In Fancybox documentation : _scrolling - Set the overflow CSS property to create or hide scrollbars. Can be set to 'auto', 'yes', 'no' or 'visible'_

Comment: Nice, I have added my comment as an answer, please validate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fancybox may help you. [fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples)

In Fancybox documentation :

> scrolling - Set the overflow CSS property to create or hide
>   scrollbars. Can be set to 'auto', 'yes', 'no' or 'visible'